# getting workDone percentage by a task in javafx

Tags: javafx

I just want to know if there is any way/technique that I can use to get the workDone (in percentage) by a task object?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an MCVE (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example):http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How about calling `task.getProgress()`?

Answer (score 0):

`task.getProgress()` will return a value between 0.0 and 1.0, so just multiply by 100 and you'll have a % value:

```
double percentComplete = task.getProgress()*100;
```